# Computer using wrong driver for network printer

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer

We have an HP plotter installed on a print server that is using a particular driver, but when we install it from the server, the client computer is using some generic Microsoft one.

I asked the server team to look into why this could be happening but they just returned the ticket to me saying they don't manage computers and the driver on the server is correct (which it does appear so).

I'm stumped as to why this is happening. Any ideas?

Powershell output, checking the printer on the server vs installed on a computer:

```
PS C:\> Get-Printer -cn SERVERNAME | Select Name, DriverName | Where Name -Like "*PLOTTER" | Format-List

Name       : *****-PLOTTER
DriverName : HP DesignJet T2600dr V4


PS C:\> Get-Printer | Select Name, DriverName | Where Name -Like "*PLOTTER" | Format-List

Name       : \\SERVERNAME\*****-PLOTTER
DriverName : Microsoft enhanced Point and Print driver
```

[image: Screenshot of printer properties]

Comment: Hi John, the driver is installed on my computer. If I install this printer manually by IP I can select the driver and it works fine (and this is the workaround I'm providing for a few individual users). However, we'd like for the process to be simple for the end user. All other printers are easily installable by just navigating to the print server in File Explorer and double-clicking the printer.

Answer (score 1):

This will *correctly* occur when you set the printer driver on the print server to *not* render on client computers (setting is on SHARING tab. imgur is blocked from here as an ostensibly dangerous/compromised site; I can’t post a picture of the dialog). This configuration causes the client computer to send a generic Windows print control language to the server, and the server uses the driver installed there to actually convert the gwpcl into device commands. Often, however, you will need a supplemental program supplied by the printer manufacturer to be deployed to the client computers to be able to have fine control over parameters for a specific job (for example, with recent Xerox printers, this is the "Xerox Print Experience").

If you set the driver on the server to "Render on client computers", when the printer is deployed (e.g., by Group Policy) to the workstation, the workstation will download and install the actual driver. However, this is only reliable with Mode 4 drivers if you have applied all of the patches that ostensibly fix PrintNightmare.

Answer (score -1):

This normally occurs if the driver for the device is not installed.

See
[Software and Drivers for HP DesignJet T2600dr 36-in PostScript Multifunction Printer](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/hp-designjet-t2600-multifunction-printer-series/model/26285334).
This page contains (too many) driver downloads. I suggest only looking
at the recent ones.
Installing a driver requires administrator permissions.

You could start with the "HP Print and Scan Doctor for Windows",
which is supposed to analyze your problem, but which might not
detect the printer. In that case, you will need to install the
drivers. If unclear which one to install, there is no problem
with installing too many of them.

The best method for getting the right driver is usually to connect
the printer physically to the client, to be correctly detected.
I don't know if this is feasible in your context.